# Bandit level 23 -> 24 doesn't seem to work, why does my solution not work?

Tags: bash, ssh

I am currently solving the overthewire.org/wargame/bandit problems. I reached level 23 -> 24 and even though I looked up solutions on the internet and copied them, it does not seem to work. It looks like the problem has been modified a bit since all the solutions online has been written, even a solution from march 2023. The problem executes and deletes all scripts in the /var/spool/bandit24/foo directory in the current version, but in the online solutions, the /foo folder is omitted from the path.

See the problem description here: https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit24.html

To solve the problem I first looked in the /etc/cron.d directory and found a cronjob_bandit24 file. It specifies a job running a script every minute. The script has the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

myname=$(whoami)

cd /var/spool/$myname/foo || exit 1
echo "Executing and deleting all scripts in /var/spool/$myname/foo:"
for i in * .*;
do
    if [ "$i" != "." -a "$i" != ".." ];
    then
        echo "Handling $i"
        owner="$(stat --format "%U" ./$i)"
        if [ "${owner}" = "bandit23" ]; then
            timeout -s 9 60 ./$i
        fi
        rm -rf ./$i
    fi
done
```

It is the bandit24 user that runs it, so it basically cd's into /var/spool/bandit24/foo (in all online solutions this is /var/spool/bandit24 only), then executes and deletes all scripts owned by bandit23 user.

The objective is to retrieve the password located at /etc/bandit_pass/bandit24, which only the bandit24 user can read, so I need to create a script that is executed by bandit24 which puts the password into a file bandit23 can read. So I created a temporary folder /tmp/temporary, in here I made a script called script.sh with the following content:

```
#!bin/bash
cat /etc/bandit_pass/bandit24 > /tmp/temporary/password
```

I then ran `touch password` to create the password file, then change the folder and file permissions to 777 with `chmod 777 -R /tmp/temporary`, I also checked with `ls -la`, everything is correct. I then copy the script with `cp script.sh /var/spool/bandit24/foo`, then wait until the script is executed and deleted, I checked with `cat /var/spool/bandit24/foo/script.sh`, initially the file exists with the expected content, then at some point within a minute it is gone, as expected. I would then expect that the password is now copied into the password file, but it is still empty. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issue it tells you about (`#!bin/bash` vs `#!/bin/bash`). Why did you tag your question with `ssh`?

Comment: Just because I ssh the passwords are used to ssh into new bandit users on the bandit host

Comment: You don't need `[ "$i" != "." -a "$i" != ".." ];`, because `.*` wouild not include `.` and `..` in the expansion. However I would do a `shopt -s nullglob` to avoid error message, if there  are no files in the directory `foo`.

Comment: Also it makes sense to execute `$i` only if it is executable, but you don't test this.

Comment: @user1934428 I did not create that script, that is the cron job that the game provides, I cannot change it

Comment: @EdMorton It was the #!/bin/bash, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your password file. you need to set 777 permissions on the file you're writing the password to in your tmp directory.

Comment: See comments on the question. The problem was a bad shebang, nothing to do with permissions. Moreover, `777` is _never_ appropriate, ever, for anything. Even as an attacker you're better off not using it: you don't want to give another attacker who compromises a different service account a leg up on replacing your foothold with something under their control.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the only reason I used a 777 set permission it because this exercise specifically calls for you to use it. It's okay to use it in this setting as it's a training exercise for something specific. I did miss the slash missing in the shebang though, but from this text 'I then ran touch password to create the password file, then change the folder and file permissions to 777 with chmod 777 -R /tmp/temporary' it seemed he forgot to set the permissions for the password file. Thank you for your input on the subject though, I do agree with you!

Comment: Granted, we have one process creating the files and another running them, but even then there's no need for `+w` on the run side. That said -- because Stack Overflow locks in votes (after a grace period) until an answer is edited, if you want to [edit] your answer to include the rationale for why 777 is correct in the context of the exercise at hand, that'll free my hand to change my vote.